Silo compilation error: no match for ‘operator<<’
Compile Silo and get the following error
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char>’} and ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long unsigned int>’)
  319 |     ss << *begin++;
      |     ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~

./util.h causes the error
template <typename ForwardIterator>
std::string
format_list(ForwardIterator begin, ForwardIterator end)
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << "[";
  bool first = true;
  while (begin != end) {
    if (!first)
      ss << ", ";
    first = false;
    ss << *begin++;  // here
  }
  ss << "]";
  return ss.str();
}

It seems this is a bug in Silo itself. I'm working on Debian 12@Linux 5.15.19. I’d like to know how to compile Silo correctly, thank you!

Silo website: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2522713
Silo repo: https://github.com/stephentu/silo

See above. (I have to write 20 characters)

Yes, it's a bug. std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, long unsigned int> doesn't have an operator<< overload for streaming (unless that's a very recent addition, but I doubt that).

fwiw the error is not in the code you posted, but in the code that instantiates the template function. The template is fine with any iterator type whose value type has a operator<<, but there is none for std::pair. The complete message would point you to the point of instantiation

Miya: I noticed that you did the right thing and wrote an error report in the Silo repo. +1

The bug is that operator<< is declared for std::pair later in the util.h file. That means lookup for << from format_list can't find it. Normally lookup should find operator overloads via ADL regardless of declaration order at the point of instantiation, but for that to work the overload must be defined in a namespace scope associated with the argument types, i.e. std here, where the user is not allowed to place such an overload. This is a common mistake and happened to work for a long time on GCC because of a bug in the compiler's lookup.

@user17732522 wasn't that a special case rhat allows to exxpand std? Also this code would work in MS compiler (doesn't respect ADL limits) and some compatible to it, which might be the reason of bug.

@Swift-FridayPie No, generally only adding partial/explicit specializations of class templates is permitted (e.g. std::hash). Adding functions to std is not permitted.

@Swift-FridayPie It shouldn't work in MSVC's standard-conforming mode either, maybe in the non-standard old lookup rules it followed. As I mentioned in my comment, another likely reason would be that GCC used to do it wrong as well. Has been fixed for GCC 12, I think.

@Swift-FridayPie There are also good reasons for these rules. Otherwise it would be easy to accidentally violate ODR by causing to template instantiations of the same specialization to use different operator overloads. Only the owner of a type should overload operators for it, only in the same namespace and in the same header.

@user17732522 it worked correctly in GCC 8s? unless they broke it later, which is possible. MS did that since day immemorial,actually since times when they used STL code (i.e. before ADL was a thing). Yeah, it leads sometimes to weird ODR issues. Also which compliant mode you mean? One that called compiant by them is ISO-non-compliant, MS-coding-standard-compliant mode

@Swift-FridayPie It was probably always wrong (according to ISO C++) in GCC until GCC 12, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577. I am talking about the ISO C++ standard conformance. But you are right that MSVC seems to still incorrectly (according to ISO C++) lookup the operator overload, even in ISO C++ conformance mode (https://godbolt.org/z/9GWxYYffz). That's surprising, because it can cause valid ISO C++ code to behave incorrectly.

@user17732522 ah, yes, in 4.7 it exist. Alongwith some confusion what a function or typename is in template code.  I actually saw that it was matching (mostly) behaviour of vs2005 compiler back then. Bugs were spotted when environment was upgraded.  THis is a problem, because most ofprogrammers consider ADL's correct behaviour a bug - most of the time in production they don't want that rule to apply. Dunno, maybe we currently use retrofitted gcc strains (both target Linux and compiler aren't for a mainstream CPU arch), but our production uses GCC 8.3 and GCC12, both do behave.

@user17732522 I tried to follow your answer and moved the operator overload before format_list. This works for me.

Thank you all for answering my question.
